# Can python's string format operator be applied to a class?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I was wondering if the string formatting operator , '`%`', can be applied to a class with subclasses in python, as seen below:

```py
"I'm %(foo.name)s!" % class
```

I know it can be applied to a dictionary, but it doesn't seem to be able to access values in multidimensional dictionaries as far as I am aware.

Comment: No, you really should be using `.format` or f-strings if you can anyway.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you use classes with ``.format``?

Comment: @user24343 Yes, you can use the \_\_format\_\_ magic method to implement formatting with a format string for a class.

Comment: Classes have a special ``__dict__`` attribute, so __theoretically__, like when passed dynamic class attributes as strings, _for demonstration purposes_, you could achieve similar behavior

Comment: @Plutoberth thanks, I was interpreting the example as ``foo`` being an instance and accessed f-string like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do `% class` but that shouldn't be troublesome because you will normally want to print a class instance. You can do what you want with a class instance. Given this class:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
```

you can do

```
>>> foo = Foo("Bar",1)
>>> f"I'm a {foo.name}"
"I'm a Bar"
```

or, if you're not using Python 3.7 yet

```
>>> "I'm a {.name}".format(foo)
"I'm a Bar"
```

and if you really want to use the `%` operator

```
>>> "I'm a %(name)s" % vars(foo)
"I'm a Bar"
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers eveything I wanted to know!